# L’omission de la préposition « de » est-elle correcte dans « Du point de vue (de l’)éthique » et dans « Du point de vue (du) sens »?

Tags: expressions, prépositions, expressions-idiomatiques, constructions, formulation

Du point de vue de l’éthique.

Du point de vue éthique.

Du point de vue du sens.

Du point de vue sens.

Quand peut-on se passer de la préposition « de » dans l’expression « du point de vue de/au point de vue de »?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Le mot éthique est un adjectif et un nom. Les deux constructions sont donc valables. La première expression suppose peut-être que l'on a en vu une éthique particulière (selon Aristote ou selon la religion ou...) alors que la deuxième est moins ciblée, mais je ne suis pas sûr que cette distinction soit perçue dans une conversation.
Quant au mot sens, il est un nom, mais non un adjectif. La construction de la 4e expression s'entend parfois, mais j'aurais tendance à croire qu'elle est fautive.